# Google docs button with text output

Tags: button, text, google-docs

I am trying my hand at a bit of code, I'm not trained in anything so it's just trial and error.

I want to be able to create a button in Google docs that generates a text output. So for example I press 'Hello World' and when I click it I get the text (on another page or document) 'Hello this is world reporting for duty.' or whatever.

I understand I need to connect the button to be able to run the script, and this was what I was thinking of:

```js
function myFunction() {
var doc  = DocumentApp.openById('XX');

 body.insertParagraph(0, "Hello this is world reporting for duty.");
 body.insertHorizontalRule(0);
 body.insertParagraph(0, "An example.");
}
```

Am I going about it the right way? At the moment Google says I need to verify my app to run this,  but I'll be using it within Google so it seems unlikely?

Anything that can point me in the right direction would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you cannot create buttons in Google Docs. You can make this work in Sheets, but Docs does not have that functionality.

What you can do is add a custom menu and tie that to a function that inserts some text.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('Hello World!', 'menuItemHelloWorld')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItemHelloWorld() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().editAsText().appendText('Hello World!\n\n');
}
```

Google will throw up some security warnings, but to test your own code you can bypass that by going to the Advanced Options (bottom left on the dialog). That will allow you to ignore the safety warning and execute your Hello World menu button.